# How can I Get text from a web element using C#

Tags: c#, html, selenium

HTML CODE

```
<span id="lbl_OrderNum" class="ff1 fs12 fwb " style="font-size:18px;">      eSYS9778</span>
```

C# CODE

```
driver.FindElementById("lbl_OrderNum").GetAttribute("textContent"); 
Console.WriteLine("textContent");
```

How can I use A get text or get attribute to save the text in my selenium code?

Comment: May I ask what have you tried already?

Comment: driver.FindElementById("lbl_OrderNum").GetAttribute("textContent");
            Console.WriteLine("textContent");

Comment: Element returned by `driver.FindElementById` should have a `Text` property.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking and your code looks like you don't understand the basics of programming or Selenium. I would suggest that you spend some time reading some Selenium tutorials. There are plenty out there that show examples just like this that you can learn from.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that using textContent only works in Firefox, if you are using chrome or IE you will need to use the

```
GetAttribute("innerText")
```